# How can i add country phone number in phone field by selecting countries by separate option list

Tags: javascript, html

i want to add a country code phone to a separate phone field in a from. E.g. ich selcet "Austria" in an option field and after selectiong the code "+41" should appera in the phone field.

This works fine with using the values BUT the values should not be changed to numbers or country name + code.. so my question ist to read the id (or anoter attribute) and place this value to the phone field...

```js
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$('#country').change(function () {
    var countryCode = $(this).val();

    if (countryCode) {
        $('#phone').val(countryCode);
    }
});
</script>
```

```html
<select name="country" id="country">
    <option value="">Country...</option>
    <option value="Belgium" id="+42">Belgien</option>
<option value="Bulgaria" id="+47">Bulgarien</option>
<option value="Croatia" id="+12">Kroatien</option>
<option value="Czech Republic" id="+28">Tschechien</option>
</select>
<br /><br />
<!-- <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
<input id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="user's number " required="" type="number"> <br><br>
 -->
```

Comment: Just make another text box called country code, make it read-only, and populate it's value on drop down change. Then the user won't be able to change it and you can just prepend that value to the phone number the user enters.

Comment: The point is that this phone field must be one field including the country code and the phone number added by user. 
It should be possible to read the ID and set the value of the ID into the phone field

Comment: Only Sith deal in absolutes.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to add a new `span` element or any tag that will hold your country code and which is not editable. Since, the country code is being selected from the dropdown you can make that code static in `span`. Also, the another reason is your phone number is a `number` type input so it will be easy to separate out the country code with `+` and allow user to add their phone number in the `input`. Now, when you submit the form or save this value to backend then at that time simply get the country code value and phone number to pass them to backend and save accordingly.

```js
$('#country').change(function () {
    var countryCode = $('#country option:selected').attr('id');
    if (countryCode) {
      $('#countryCode').text(countryCode);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="country" id="country">
    <option value="">Country...</option>
    <option value="Belgium" id="+42">Belgien</option>
<option value="Bulgaria" id="+47">Bulgarien</option>
<option value="Croatia" id="+12">Kroatien</option>
<option value="Czech Republic" id="+28">Tschechien</option>
</select>
<br /><br />

<label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
<span id='countryCode'></span>
<input id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="user's number " required="" type="number"> <br><br>
```

Comment: I solved it by adding new attribute: data

<option value="Germany" data-code="+49  ">Deutschland</option>

and changed the var values in JS:

var countryCode = $(this).find(':selected').data('code');

...this works excellent